# Ignore files from subfolders

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a project with directory uploads/ which has subdirectories /images and /files.
I want to ignore commiting files from these two subdirectories uploads/images and uploads/files but i want .gitignore file to be in root directory.

Comment: Just add those two to your `.gitignore` then. What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: This is one of the most frequently asked questions in the [git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tag. Please make sure to search before submitting a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore all files in a folder with a git repository in SourceTree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665399/how-to-ignore-all-files-in-a-folder-with-a-git-repository-in-sourcetree)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add in the `.gitignore`:

```
/uploads/images/
/uploads/files/
```

That will ignore the content of those folders, provided they were not already versioned.
If they were, you would need to remove them from the index and commit (recording the deletion from the repo, not from the disk: `--cached`)

```
git rm -r --cached uploads/images
git rm -r --cached uploads/files
```

> but this ignore even the folders, not only content, I want to ignore only content of those folders

One trick is to ignore the all folder (as described above), and *then* do:

```
touch uploads/images/.keep
git add --force uploads/images/.keep
touch uploads/files/.keep
git add --force uploads/files/.keep
git commit -m "keep fodlers"
```

That means you need to have *some* content in order to keep the folder in the repo (an empty folder would not be tracked by Git).

Comment: but this ignore even the folders, not only content, I want to ignore only content of those folders

Comment: @PYovchevski Git doesn't track directories. At all. Ever.

Comment: @PYovchevskiI have edited the answer in order to keep the folder while ignoring their content