# how to make files untracked in source tree . I want to create and retain some files locally

Tags: git, sourcetree

I have some .java files that I want to retain local, I never want to push to origin. how can I say to source tree that please don't track these files.

Comment: Add those files to your .gitignore file. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23035828/2295034

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore all files in a folder with a git repository in SourceTree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665399/how-to-ignore-all-files-in-a-folder-with-a-git-repository-in-sourcetree)